# Validation error ...........: Value '<TestStream>' at 'streamName' failed to satisfy constraint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kinesis

Getting error when I am trying to migrate stream data from MYSQL to Kinesis. Help me to fix this.

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutRecord operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '' at 'streamName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+

```
import json
import boto3
import pymysql
import socket,array
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pymysqlreplication import BinLogStreamReader
from pymysqlreplication.row_event import (
    DeleteRowsEvent,
    UpdateRowsEvent,
    WriteRowsEvent,
)
class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

connection = {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 3306,
    "user": "root",
    "passwd": "root"}

def main():
  kinesis = boto3.client("kinesis",region_name='ap-south-1')
  stream = BinLogStreamReader(
            connection_settings=connection,
            only_events=[DeleteRowsEvent, WriteRowsEvent, UpdateRowsEvent],
            server_id=100,
            blocking=True,
            log_file='mysql-bin.000003',
            resume_stream=True,
        )
  for binlogevent in stream:
    for row in binlogevent.rows:
      event = {"schema": binlogevent.schema,
      "table": binlogevent.table,
      "type": type(binlogevent).__name__,
      "row": row
      }       
      kinesis.put_record(StreamName="<MysqlKinesisStream>", Data=json.dumps(event,cls=DateTimeEncoder), 
PartitionKey="default",)
      print (json.dumps(event))
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the name `"<TestStream>"` is an invalid Kinesis stream name. Use the Kinesis stream name you created in AWS.

Kinesis names must match the regex pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+`

Comment: Yes. I have used the same Stream name , which I have created in kinesis. I cross chcked.

Comment: Please create a stream with a name that matches syntax [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+. The left and right arrow are the problem

Comment: I have created another one but still showing the same error. Can you please show me one example for this syntax.

Comment: What is your new stream name? A valid example is `TestStream`

Comment: I put mysql-KINESIS_Stream.20

Comment: Can you paste the new version of your script with this change in?

Comment: I have done the changes. Please look at my above code once.

Comment: You set stream name to `<MysqlKinesisStream>` it should just be `MysqlKinesisStream`

Comment: when I changed to ""kinesis.put_record(StreamName="MysqlKinesisStream", Data=json.dumps(event,cls=DateTimeEncoder), PartitionKey="default",)"" Error: 
 botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the PutRecord operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Comment: Right, that would be a new issue. You need to ensure the IAM credentials being used are valid

Comment: Also this is not my compile time error. When I fire any query for insert from phpmyadmin then at that instance only the error show.

Comment: Thanks ... I am able to migrate data to kinesis after configuring my IAM profile.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there may have been an issue with an extra blank or space that was in *front* of the stream name when you added it as a environment variable value in the Configuration tab for your lambda?  That is what happened to me.  Somehow there was a preceding blank before my stream name when I entered it as a value under the Configuration KEY VALUE pairs and I kept getting that error and I was wondering to myself if it could really have an extraneous character at the beginning of the stream name string.

As soon as I made that update to remove that preceding space from the stream name string, everything worked which is exactly what the grep string in the error exception message was indicating (no blanks nor #,$@ or any other strange character should be in the stream name string):

> {
> "URL": "https://7rai4b8gwk.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/events?test=1",
> "error": "",
> "response_body": {
> "message": "**success**"
> },
> "response_status_code": 200
> }

Before that, I got the exception but also got"

> {
> "URL": "https://7rai4b8gwk.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/events?test=1",
> "error": "",
> "response_body": {
> "message": "**process failed 2**"
> },
> "response_status_code": 200
> }